# Access DaggerComponent defined in java from kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, dagger-2

I need to use existing dagger component from my new kotlin class. The problem is that when I compile, the component that I use in kotlin class is not generated, so I receive an error:

`Unresolved reference: DaggerCustomComponent`

I'm pretty sure it's caused by kotlin, because as soon as I remove or comment all the usages of the DaggerCustomComponent in that kotlin class, it all magically starts to work.

I tried to fix that by adding this to my module's gradle file

`apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"`

then I did a clean build and now it doesn't compile at all:

`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'. > Internal compiler error. See log for more`

I've seen lots of tutorials but none of them mentioned that their components were defined in java code, I guess that might be a problem too

Comment: what does the log say?

Comment: kaptKotlin(Debug) will generate DaggerCustomComponent, so you must find out why that task fails